# Regexp Pattern for matching Numbers with units and special symbols (ex. "120% g" etc.) and special grouping them

Tags: regex

I would like to build Regexp pattern matcher which could match next possibilities:

```
11
2.5 
ca. 111g                   
ca. 120 g Case
11 Kilograms
12.5-125.0 g
ca. 120% g
```

In this cases I should become always 4 groups (use "ca. 12.5-125.0% g" as example):

1. **ca.** *(everything what is before numbers)*
2. **12.5-125.0** *()*
3. **g** *(units)*
4. **%** *(any special symbols after number)*

I have already build this regex, but it's not working as I want in all situations above:
`(\d*[.]?[-]?\d+(?:\s*|\s+))(\w*)(\D)`. For example, groups are not build correct everytime and sometimes "g" lands in third group and sometimes in fourth..

Comment: Try `(?:([a-zA-Z]+)\.\s*)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*-\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)([^\w\s]*)\s*([a-zA-Z]*)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/HCFomg/2))

Comment: Please provide *examples* of what inputs don't work the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

The possibility of g landing in the third or the fourth group is due to the fact that `\D` matches any char except a digit, which can also match chars a-z as `\w` can.

So for example in this string `1ga` the g is in group 2. In this string `1g` the g is in group 3, as the word characters are optional and `\D` expects at least a single char.

Note that this part of the pattern `(?:\s*|\s+)` can be written as `\s*`. You can use `\s` in the pattern, but it can also possibly match a newline.

---

One option could be making the pattern a bit more specific and list the allowed special symbols in a character class `[%]?`

```
^(?:(\w+\.) )?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+))?)([%]?)(?: ?(\w+))?
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:(\w+\.) )?` Optionally match a trailing space after capture **group 1**,
  which matches 1+ word chars and a dot
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
  - `(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+))?` Optionally match `-` and 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 2
- `([%]?)` Capture **group 3**, match an optional "special" char
- `(?: ?(\w+))?` Optionally match a space and capture **group 4** to match 1+ word characters

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CqV99m/1)

Without an anchor, you could also use word boundary `\b` and if the dot at the beginning is not always there, you can make it optional `\.?`

```
\b(?:(\w+\.?) )?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+))?)([%]?)(?: ?(\w+))?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4vZqAu/1)

Comment: Hello, I found, that this regex is not working in situation when before number are only whitespaces, for. ex. `_100g` (let's denote `_` as whitespace) or when String before Numbers does not constain dot, ex. `max 110 cm`. Of course, in first situation I can easly trim input String before matching. Thank you.

Comment: @Dawid You could make the dot optional for example and for the spaces before the number you can use a word boundary instead of an anchor `\b(?:(\w+\.?) )?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+))?)([%]?)(?: ?(\w+))?` https://regex101.com/r/4vZqAu/1  or match spaces before the first number https://regex101.com/r/vFev8L/1